# I keep on getting these error in F-RCNN when I train the model

Tags: keras, computer-vision, transfer-learning, faster-rcnn

When I run it for 1000 epochs in between it also gives similar exception and after it's finished with 1000 epochs, it continues iterations of these same exceptions. Github code for the model - https://github.com/bhatt-priyadutt/blink-rate

```
Exception: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: slice index 2 of dimension 1 out of bounds.
     [[node roi_pooling_conv_1/strided_slice_13 (defined at usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
     [[add_22/_305]]
  (1) Invalid argument: slice index 2 of dimension 1 out of bounds.
     [[node roi_pooling_conv_1/strided_slice_13 (defined at usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'roi_pooling_conv_1/strided_slice_13':
  File "content/blink-rate/train_frcnn.py", line 134, in <module>
    classifier = nn.classifier(shared_layers, roi_input, C.num_rois, nb_classes=len(classes_count), trainable=True)
  File "content/blink-rate/keras_frcnn/resnet.py", line 239, in classifier
    out_roi_pool = RoiPoolingConv(pooling_regions, num_rois)([base_layers, input_rois])
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 578, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "content/blink-rate/keras_frcnn/RoiPoolingConv.py", line 65, in call
    h = rois[0, roi_idx, 3]
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 802, in _slice_helper
    name=name)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 968, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 10392, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
Exception: index 1000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000
Exception: index 1000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000
Exception: index 1000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000
2021-09-26 15:41:01.791109: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:108 : Invalid argument: slice index 6 of dimension 1 out of bounds.
2021-09-26 15:41:01.791144: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:108 : Invalid argument: slice index 4 of dimension 1 out of bounds.
```